# Monty Hall Variation: Choosing 2 Doors

Tags: monty-hall

I'm learning about the Monty Hall problem, and found a question which has confused me:

> Consider the following four-door Monty Hall problem:
>   Step 1: you
>   choose one door such as door 1.
>   Step 2: Monty Hall opens one door
>   with no car behind, such as door 2.
>   Step 3: Monty Hall asks you to
>   decide whether you like to “stick with your current door or choose
>   another door” such as door 3 or “switch to the other two doors” such
>   as doors 3 and 4.
>
> You will win the car if it is behind either of the two chosen doors.
>
> Now apply Bayes’ theorem to calculate the probabilities of winning the
>   car by the following two choices: **1) stick and choose another door;
>   2) switch to the two other doors.**

Original question image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/czPth.png

I know to set my initial probabilities of the car being behind each door to:
**{1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}**

How does my working of the problem change, now that I am choosing 2 doors, rather than one?

I have tried reducing the problem to it being between:
*"Do we stick and choose, or switch and switch?"*

This is quite confusing. Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Comment: Should _“stick with your current door or choose another door”_ be _“stick with your current door **and** choose another door”_? Otherwise I don't see how there are two options instead of three.

Comment: Note that there are some excellent answers to the regular five door problem here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032661/monty-hall-problem-with-five-doors?rq=1

Comment: Basically everyone is a bit confused about exactly what you're asking. Could you clarify exactly what my options are as a player of the game?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear about the assumptions: let us suppose I picked door $A$, and Monty Hall revealed door $B$ because he knew there was no car behind door $B$. Then I have three options: I can open doors $C$ and $D$ ("switch"), or I can open doors $A$ and $C$, or I can open doors $A$ and $D$ (both these options being "stick").

With probability $1/4$, we originally picked the door with the car. Then we get a car if we stick, and we lose the car if we switch.

With probability $3/4$, we did not pick the door with the car. Then: if we switch, we get the car. If we stick, we have a $1/2$ chance of getting the car.

So, if we switch, the probability is $\frac{3}{4}$ of getting the car. If we stick, the probability is $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{8}$.
So it is better to switch. (Thanks, Mathmo123, for pointing out that $\frac{3}{4} > \frac{5}{8}$.)

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, I'll call the door you first chose $A,$ the empty door shown as $B,$
and the other two doors as $C$ and $D$

P(win by not switching) $= \dfrac14$

*Scenario $1$, you switch to $C$*
P(win) = P(not behind $A$) * P(behind $C$ | not behind $A) = \dfrac34\cdot\dfrac12 = \dfrac38$

*Scenario $2$, you switch to cover both* $C$ and $D$
P(win) = P(not behind $A$) * P(behind $C\cup D$| not behind $A) = \dfrac34\cdot\dfrac22 = \dfrac34$

---

If scenario $1$ means you are in effect choosing $A$ *and* one from $C$ or $D$, say $C$,

P(win) = P(behind $A$) + P(not behind $A$) * P(behind $C$ | not behind $A) = \dfrac14 + \dfrac34\cdot\dfrac12 = \dfrac58$

Answer (score 0):

After the revelation, the probabilities are
$$(1/4,0,3/8,3/8) $$
So switching to a single other door will increase the winning probability from $\frac14$ to $\frac38$. Switching to both other doors will increase it to $\frac 34$.

Comment: I think if we start with door $A$ and Monty Hall reveals door $B$, we have the choice between picking doors $A$ and $C$ or doors $C$ and $D$. Your answer is based on having the choice between door $C$, door $D$, or doors $C$ and $D$, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Before he opens the door, the chance your original choice is correct is $\frac{1}{4}$. After he opens the door, that remains true, so the chance that the other two doors are correct is $\frac{3}{8}$ for each. If you take the option of picking one to add to your existing choice, your chance of winning is $\frac{5}{8}$. If you switch to the other two your chance of winning is $\frac{6}{8}$.