# How to solve monty hall with 5 doors using bayes theorem?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem, monty-hall

With 5 doors we get the following events.

`A:` Probability of choosing a door with a car behind it: `1/5`

`B|A:` Likelihood of monty opened door B if door A contains a car: `1/4` ? Im not sure about this one

How can I proceed now?

With 5 doors he will open 3 doors. Door A is the door I choose, door B is the one monty left closed.

How can I obtain the probability that the car is actually behind door B? That is if i switched from door A from door B.

The result supposedly is `4/15` but i cannot achieve using bayes theorem.

Can someone guide me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: The result of what?  What are you supposed to calculate?

Comment: I just edited my question @Bram28

Comment: Isn't B the door that Monty opens? I think you want the probability of getting the car when swithcing to door C ....

Comment: With 5 doors he will open 3 doors. I said door B, but door B is an arbitrary name for the other door.
Door A is the door I choose, door B is the one monty left closed.

Comment: Ah!  Maybe put that in the question as well .. I thought Monty still just opened one door ... door B. In fact, isn't switching always supposed to be better? So why is the result less than $\frac{1}{2}$? That would suggest that switching to door B is worse than staying with door A.  Hmmmm, so maybe the fact that you are having problems getting to the right solution is because you misunderstood the question? Maybe Monty is really opening just one door?

Comment: Im not sure. I found the 4/15 from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032661/monty-hall-problem-with-five-doors

Comment: Aha!  Yes, it's right there: Monty opens *one* of the other doors and then invites you to switch to one of the remainig closed doors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110667/discussion-between-pedro-martins-and-bram28).

Comment: This does not use Bayes' theorem explicitly, but you can see this directly using the symmetry: not switching yields you probability 1/5. If you switch, then you have equal probability for each of the other doors, which makes it $\frac{4}{5}\cdot \frac {1}{3}=\frac 4{15}$.

Comment: You say the problem is from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032661/monty-hall-problem-with-five-doors but the problem you describe is *different*.  There monty shows you *one* door.  You  can stay, or you can switch. And if you switch there are three doors you can switch to. The prob is 4/15 for any of the other door**s**.  The problem *you* gave Monty shows you *three* doors and leaves you one to switch to.  The probability if you switch if 4/5.   A completely different problem!  And a completely different answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are *not at all* interested in the probability that Monty chooses a particular door.   You are entirely concerned about the probability that another door hides the prise when given that Monty always reveals *one which does not*.

So the events of interest are *the car is behind the first chosen door (A)* and *the car is behind the door you would switch to (C)*.

Well, if the prise is behind the first door, switching surely loses, *else if* it is not behind the A-door, then after Monty reveals another door where it is not, the prize is equally likely to be behind *each of the three* remaining doors.

Thus we evaluate the marginal probability that *switching wins* as:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(C)&=\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(C\mid A)+\mathsf P(A^\complement)\,\mathsf P(C\mid A^\complement)\\&=\tfrac 15\tfrac 03+\tfrac 45\tfrac 13\\&=\tfrac 4{15}\end{align}$$

---

Note that the probability that *staying wins* is $3/15$, so *this game* still makes switching the better option, though only slightly.

Comment: PS: Rather than Bayes' Theorem, the rule used is The Law of Total Probability.